# Sending an Array into a PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: arrays, plsql, service, cursor

I have created a Web Service to send in a bunch of information to a PL/SQL procedure, however one of them is a array. What type do I use for this? I also want to put that array into a cursor after it comes in.

Comment: What language is the web service written in?  How does it connect to the database?  What specific datatype is the "array" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with PL/SQL, so sorry if this doesn't apply.  In MS SQL 2000/2005, there isn't a way to pass arrays into a procedure; I'm assuming PL/SQL has a similar limitation.  The workaround I've used in the past is to pass in a delimited string (usually pipe delimited because commas were present in the data), and then have a function that can take a delimited string and break it up into a table result with one row per value.  Then inside your procedure, you just call your split function passing it the delimited string and you have a table result that you can do whatever you want with (cursor over, join to other tables, etc).

EDIT: Just did a google for "PL/SQL table parameter" and had a few hits; Might be worth investigating to see if any of those results can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/70369/0/) might be of use.  Or you can do what the other poster said and basically serialize your data into a string, pass it, and then unserialize it on the other end.